# decrease x-axis font on a plot in R

Tags: r, plot, fonts

I would like to decrease the font size of the x-axis so it fits the country names.

I have tried `cex`, `cex.axis`, `axis()` and nothing has seemed to work. `cex` and `cex.axis` have changed the Y-axis only. Here is the code I have been using.

```
plot(goldmanMF20to50$Location, xlab="Location", ylab="Number of Individuals", 
     col=4, main="Location of Individuals in the Goldman Osteometric Data Set 
     between 20 and 50", cex.main=0.6, las = 2, ylim=c(0, 150),)
```

Comment: You probably need to use something like: `plot(..., xaxt="n"); axis(1, ... , cex.axis=.5)`

Comment: thank you but what are the … for?

Comment: and that also makes the words turn into numbers @BondedDust. Any thoughts? thanks again

Comment: The ellipses are for other arguments. Unclear that "that" actually means. Do remember that we cannot see your console. My practice is to offer complete coding when an example is offered.

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply directly to this question, but the solution when working with dates is to initially suppress x-axis labels and subsequently plot the x-axis with the axis.Date() command. This requires creating a separate x-axis data set--in the example below this is generated in the dates file. Here's an example by plotting stock market data (S&P 500). Note the xaxt="n" parameter in plot() and the relatively small font size in axis.Date() via cex.axis=0.8

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("^GSPC", src='yahoo', from='2013-12-31')
sp500 <-Ad(GSPC)

dates <-as.Date(index(sp500))

plot(dates,sp500, ylab = "",xlab="",xaxt="n",type="l")
axis.Date(side = 1, dates,at = dates,cex.axis=0.8,format = "%b-%d-%Y")
```